# offered courses to students

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, weblogic-10.x

I am confused with the logic when a students gets offered courses in a semester. these are the tables i have;

```
Class
Course
Semester
```

Now, the current schema is such as Admin selects list of courses which will be offered in Computer Science Degree in a semester say Fall 2014.

Now, a student in 4th Semester shall be offered different courses than students in 3rd semester and so on. at this last point i am confused how to separate courses offered into semesters (1, 2 and so on)

Here is the schema

Class

```
class_id (int)
class_year (int) 
class_semester (int) F.K
class_course (int) F.K
class_status (int) F.K
```

Semester

```
sem_id (int)
Sem_name (varchar 100)
```

course

```
course_id (int)
course_code(varchar 10)
course_name (varchar 100)
course_credit (int)
```

Comment: title it appropriately.

Comment: how like ? @mithunsatheesh

Comment: built database, than run the query, and you are ok

Comment: i have already database @Arif_suhail_123 http://www.khanakujast.com  username: admin and password: admin. However, the question i am asking is not uploaded on database yet

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to design and reference or link your tables in such a way as below :

For example :

```
Class Table - Suppose you have class A and Class B with class_id as column.

Semester Table- Here you will have reference to your class tables class_id 
so your semester table goes like Semester_ID / Class_ID /...

Courses Table - Here you will have reference to semester_id like course_id /semester_id /...
```

This way you can have access or can create courses specific to semester and like wise.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Regards,
Zeeshan.

Comment: What is your issue then what problem you are facing let us know clearly to help you in better way.

Comment: The problem is that i need a logic for courses that are being offered for a specific semester

Comment: You can use join to get courses for specific semester like joining class table to sem_id and course_id to resp. tables.

Let me know if you are still in doubts ?

Comment: suppose for bachelor degree typically 8 semester is required. Do i have to have additional table containing semester numbers ? at the moment my semester table has semester types values such as Summer and Fall

Comment: Yes if you want to divide your semester in terms of numbers like 1 -8 not summer or winter than you have to store your semester like wise.